# Use BATCH file to call NodeJS script in a password protected folder

Tags: node.js, batch-file, password-protection

I am trying to use a batch file to call a node script. The node script exists on a server which is password protected. How do I both call the node script and include the credentials for the path in the same batch file?

Script looks like this

```
CLS
@ECHO OFF

node "\\[server_name]\d$\[path_name]\GetDynamicTeams.js"

if NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    pause 
)
```

I have tried running the `net use` syntax and included the user/pass but to no avail. That looked like this

```
node net use "\\devwn12281\d$\xMattersSystems\scripts\xMatters Toolbox\GetDynamicTeams.js" /USER:alarmpoint xm2215x99=
```

Syntax wouldn't work because I can't include `node` keyword in that command.

Any ideas?

Comment: The proper syntax is `net use "\\servername\sharename" /user:username /password:*`, then run your `node` command afterward. As an aside, I would recommend creating a share with only the needed access rather than using the admin share (`d$`).

Comment: For security in depth, setup a user on the server for this specific task. Give that user a meaningful name and a very strong password.  Configure the share to allow only that user to have only the rights necessary for the task.  Restrict access to the script file containing the password and setup tasks on the server and wherever the script is stored, to change the user password frequently (90 days max).

Comment: I tried the above suggestion but it's not working... My code looks like this


`net use \\[server_name] [password] /user:[UserName ex... foo/bar] node "\\[server_name]\d$\xMattersSystems\scripts\xMatters Toolbox\GetDynamicTeams.js"`

Another example without the brackets, replacing sensitive info...

`net use \\my_server password123 /user:MyCompany/MyUser node "\\my_server\d$\xMattersSystems\scripts\xMatters Toolbox\GetDynamicTeams.js"`

Comment: You must not be trying the above suggestion correctly, as the syntax I posted is the correct syntax. (Remember, we can't see your screen.)